# Atlas Generation attribute table feature filter

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have generated a map using atlas.

I have an attribute table on the map, in this table is a column showing features. There are no records in this field, how can I turn it off / hide it so that it is not shown on the map?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which attribute columns are shown in the table by pressing the button called `Attributes` in the item properties tab. There is a longer discussion in the [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_attribute_table.html).